# How to remove parent checkbox in LI if no checkbox exists in child LI with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

```
<ul ="staffTree">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedNode" id="selectedNode" value = "Manager">
        Manager
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedNode" id="selectedNode" value = "AsstManager">
                Asst. Manager
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/not_allowed.png" title="Not Allowed">
                        Staff Member 1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/not_allowed.png" title="Not Allowed">
                          Staff Member 2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/not_allowed.png" title="Not Allowed">
                          Staff Member 3
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this example, no checkbox exists with any staff member, so I want to replace the input field of Asst. Manager with that "Not Allowed" image. 
If any checkbox exists in any li. Then the parent will also contain the checkbox. And the super parent (Manager) will also have. The tree will be of N level.

I am trying to make a jQuery selector for it. And need pointer on it.

Comment: Note you have multiple input elements with ID = selectedNode.  Ids of HTML element should be unique.  Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#staffTree li > input:checkbox').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.siblings().has('li > input:checkbox').length) {
    return;
  }
  $this.replaceWith('<img src="images/not_allowed.png" title="Not Allowed">');
});
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/823vR/

Comment: Thanks for the edit. 1) If Staff Member 1 li has the input check box. It will also diable (replace) the Asst manager, it should not. 2) If All the staff members are with images, then top Manager shold also have the image. Any pointer on it?

Comment: @TahirAkram  1)  this is not true here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/823vR/1/ . 2) this is not true as well.  Play around with the fiddle I provided you will see it handles both cases you speak of.

Comment: Thanks John let me play with it.